# Javascript Div Swap on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swap

So I have some working JS code on my site which swaps on div to another div once the link has been clicked. However I currently have it work on top of an iframe by overlaying a clear gif which is the link and it works perfectly.

Now I want to apply it to a button which is pressed on our site to create a download - I can't use the same invisible gif trick as the button has a mouse over effect which then doesn't work so I want it to happen some other way when clicking on the button. The function which currently works is loaded in the header as…

```
function yourFunction(){
    document.getElementById('yourfirDiv').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('yoursecDiv').style.display='none';
}
```

At the moment the link which triggers this is an image which works perfectly and looks as follows…

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="var fileref=document.createElement('script');fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); fileref.setAttribute('src', 'http://url.com/locker.js?guid=0512eafd69b18d22');document.body.appendChild(fileref); setTimeout(yourFunction, 3000);"> 
    <img src="http://url.com/blank.gif" style="position: absolute; z-index: 500; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 280px; "> 
</a>
```

Now I need to apply this to do the same thing on this button…

```
<div id="yoursecDiv" style="display:block;">
    <div id="downloadmp3">
        <div class="download_button_div">
            <form action="/download_file.php" method="post" name="downloadform">
                <input name="file_name" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" type="hidden">
                <input name="bucket" value="<?php echo $bucket; ?>" type="hidden">
                <button type='submit' class='download_button' title="Click to Download Mixtape!">Download</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Someone gave me some simple JS which is as follows which should trigger when a div name is clicked to trigger the function which swaps the named divs, however it doesn't work, the code snippet is…

```
$("#clickablediv").bind("click",function(){
    yourFunction();
});
```

To make things slightly more complicated, the page is a floating page launched with ajax, so any code like the above has to go in the sites JS file in the part which loads the page if it needs to be loaded on launch of a portfolio. In the case of the link above the function code loads in the global site header just fine and the inline JS works fine - perhaps there is a way to apply that link to my button divs somehow, simple inputs very welcome!

Comment: Your question is too complex. All that business about the iframe isn't relevant. Try paring your question and your code to the specific issue at hand.

Comment: Have you included the jquery library on your page?

Comment: @JonP yes jquery is there

Comment: @isherwood the iFrame link is there to show how the code words successfully already - I just need to change it to use the function in a link that will work with a div or the button - I think its relevant.

Comment: You don't have to prove it to us. Just saying so is adequate. :-) It would also help if your code was properly indented. It can be challenging enough to read other peoples code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think isherwood is correct in that you're overcomplicating things.

However, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click","#clickablediv",function(){
        $('#yourfirDiv').show();
        $('#yoursecDiv').hide();
    });
});
```

Assuming #yourfirDiv has either style or class css with "display:none".

Then you can remove those pesky onclick attributes from the divs.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried putting that code every single place I can think of, in the ajax load javascript, in the header, in the php for the portfolio page - its not doing anything, anywhere… :/ - same as the original but of code doesn't work. I only used the more complicated separate function etc as it was taken from a code snippet for the plugin i'm using and I got it worked properly. But at the moment that div isn't going anywhere...

Comment: Might it not be working because the content locker is already been trigger on click by another div in there…so its trying to launch two div on click functions at the same time - see the original iframe example both launches the content locker and then swaps the divs 3 seconds later...

Comment: btw - Firebug doesn't report any errors in console for this either.

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure that you're not getting messy click handling. Best thing to do is get everything out of the HTML into nice clean functions.

Comment: Hi Jono, Ok I've found some of the problems, it was using functions listed to divs too often. So I now have the div swapping as per your code above, but now if i have my locker trigger by CSS ID, it lauches when you click without clicking to achieve the div swap. So I somehow need to integrate opening the content locker with JS as well as performing the div swap, which is what the original link did, so I need to put these functions into your code (minutes the yourFunction part as that just triggers the delay.

Comment: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="var fileref=document.createElement('script');fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); fileref.setAttribute('src', 'http://c.themixtapesite.com/locker.js?guid=0512eafd69b18d22');document.body.appendChild(fileref); setTimeout(yourFunction, 3000);"></a>`

Comment: Yes, both need to be amalgamated into the one function / handler. Is the code you have in the onclick the other that you wish to execute? If so, then take that and put it after the hide/show in the handler. Then all will be executed in the same motion. Make sense>